# Module named "make_problem" in Python

Tags: python, module, installation

I am attempting to use a code called [PLUTO](http://plutocode.ph.unito.it/) for use in computational astrophysics. I am attempting to run the setup python file "setup.py". At the start of this script, 3 modules are imported:

```
import menu
import configure
from make_problem import MakeProblem
```

Initially i did not have the first two modules installed, but was easily able to find them online, download and install them.

However I can find no mention online of the "make_problem" module. Can anyone point me in its direction, or explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: is make_problem in PLUTO? If not, end of the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having had a quick look at this I have found a few things. make_problem.py is a file included in the PLUTO download in /Tools/Python/. I would suggest that you try copying the make_problem file to the directory with the setup.py file or to the directory with the rest of your python libraries and see what happens then.

I have also discovered that both menu and configure are modules which are also included in the PLUTO download. I don't know what other modules you downloaded but I don't think that they are required. However, I don't know why the program is not finding these modules. Are you running the setup.py file which is in the main directory or the one in Tools/Python/? The second file worked for me after some experimenting but the first still will not. Secondly, where are you running it from (as in directory accessed in terminal or command prompt)?

Comment: Perfect - i hadn't realised that there were TWO setup.py files - one in tools/python/ and one at the top of the PLUTO directory.They seem to be identical so I'm not sure why there are two... anyway this solved my problem thank you!